# How to add a child to a tree using clojure.zip?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Consider the following code

```
(def v (z/vector-zip [1 [2 [3 4]]]))
```

where z refers to clojure.zip.

Now, how do I create from v the vector

```
[1 [2 [3 [4 5]]]]
```

using functions from the API for clojure.zip ? So starting with

```
(-> 
 v 
 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use function `edit`

```
(defn edit
  "Replaces the node at this loc with the value of (f node args)"
  [loc f & args]
    (replace loc (apply f (node loc) args)))
```

Example

```
(-> v
    (z/down)
    (z/right)
    (z/down)
    (z/right)
    (z/down)
    (z/right)
    (z/edit #(do [% 5]))
    (z/root))
```

And the result will be

```
=> [1 [2 [3 [4 5]]]]
```

Comment: OK, got that now. Thanks.

Comment: Suppose the initial tree was [1 [2 [3 [4 [5 [6 7]]]]]] etc. up to say 99 or more even instead of [1 [2 [3 [4 5]]]] ... Wait. I will make a new question for that with a reference to this one.