# Follow-up to 'how to add a child to a tree using clojure.zip'?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

This question refers to and is a follow-up to question [37484870](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484870/how-to-add-a-child-to-a-tree-using-clojure-zip):

Consider the following code

```
(defn f [x]
    (loop [a x v [(inc x)]] 
      (if (> a 0) 
        (recur (dec a) (conj [a] v))
        v)))

(def v (z/vector-zip (f 10))
```

where z refers to clojure.zip. Note that 10 could have been a much larger number.

Now, how do I add a node to v using functions from the API for clojure.zip such that the result is equal to

```
((def v (z/vector-zip (f (inc 10)) ?
```

So a node is added to the left most node at the deepest level ( if that helps ).

The reason for asking this question is that the answer to question [37484870](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484870/how-to-add-a-child-to-a-tree-using-clojure-zip)
implies a loop of 10

```
(z/down)
(z/right)
```

functions but perhaps zipper structures offer a more direct solution.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solutions is

```
(-> v
    (#(let [next (z/next %)]
       (if (z/end? next)
         %
         (recur next))))
    (#(z/insert-right % [(inc (z/node %))]))
    (z/root))
```

Comment: I am thinking of a more literate solution like creating functions or macros to move to specific positions in the tree, as an addition to next, etc.